# Javascript/jQuery onclick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i made a test.html document to test a script. Somehow it is not working and i can't get why nothing is happening. The Script is in -tags and wrapped with -tag and the css also has it´s -tags. Why shouldn't it work? Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
        $('#menu li a').on('click', function() {
            $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });
        </script>
        <style>
        .current {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="about-link" class="current" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a id="events-link" href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
                <li><a id="reviews-link" href="#">REVIEWS</a></li>
                <li><a id="contact-link" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because your code for binding event handler is executed before the elements is present in `DOM`, the event is not bound on the element.

To solve this problem, you can either

1. Wrap your code in `ready()` callback, so that your code will be executed when `DOM` is finished loading
2. Move your script to the end of `<body>`, so all the elements are present in `DOM` and you can bind the events on it

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu li a').on('click', function () {
        $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

You can also use `load`(*not recommended*) event callback to bind the event, but this will wait for all the resources to load completely.

If you want to use Vanilla Javascript, you can use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event on `document`.

Comment: Note: The past-tense of *bind* is *bound* (not *binded*). i.e. "the event is not bound on the element"

Comment: Better. That seems to be the most common grammatical error on SO :) +1 for also suggesting you can simply move the code to after the elements.

Answer (score 8):

you are executing the code before the DOM content is loaded. Place your code in a ready block.

Comment: *Or* simply place the code after the elements it references... (end of `body` being the most common place)

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the JavaScript before the `<body>` tag loads, which contains your `<li>` elements.

To solve this problem, you have three choices :

1.You can insert the JavaScript code you have written inside a `$(document).ready()` callback. (see http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp for more information)

Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#menu li a').on('click', function () {
    $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
  });
});
```

2.You can use the JavaScript's built in `window.onload` function. (see https://thechamplord.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/using-javascript-window-onload-event-properly/ for more information)

Code:

```
window.onload = function () {
$('#menu li a').on('click', function () {
    $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
  });
}
```

3.Place your `<script>` tag before `</body>` tag in your page.

Code:

```
<head>
    <style>
    .current {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="about-link" class="current" href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a id="events-link" href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
            <li><a id="reviews-link" href="#">REVIEWS</a></li>
            <li><a id="contact-link" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $('#menu li a').on('click', function() {
        $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

> **Note**: Using `$(document).ready()` is a better option than using `window.onload`. (see [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready) for more information)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Just wrap it in DOM ready and you are good to go.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu li a').on('click', function() {
        $('li a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
})
```