# JQuery add active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Iam trying to add active class in the `<li>` but it's not working.

This is all my codes in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#nav li.menu').click(function () {
            $('#nav li.menu').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>

<nav id="nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="main_menu"><span class="fa fa-bars fa-lg icon_here"></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="main">MENU</span></li>
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
          <li class="menu"><a href="@Url.Action(item.sm_action_name,item.sm_controller)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@item.sm_name</a></li>
        }
     </ul>
</nav>
```

This is what displayed in the console:

[image]

Comment: Wrap the JS code in `ready`. Code `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav li.menu').click(function () {
        $('#nav li.menu').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});` OR **Move the script to the end of body**. For reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/32222881/2025923 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/32558249/2025923

Comment: where is your script placed?

Comment: I put my script code on the top

Comment: also whether the link related html is created after the page is loaded

Comment: then that is the problem... your script is executed before the dom elements related to the nav is created so none of the click handler is added to the `li` elements... so follow the answer in the first comment

Comment: @Jen143 Please add some description, of what's happening, what is not working, any error in console

Comment: Have you included jQuery on page? And included it before using it?

Comment: Yes, all jquery files are place in the BundleConfig.cs

Comment: where is your Jquery File placed?? put it on the head and also check the might be you calling two jquery files that creates the Confliction Sometimes.

Comment: @Jen143 Try `$('#nav').on('click', 'li.menu', function () {` to bind event